# Applying limit inferior

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limsup-and-liminf

[image]

In the solution to this question while attempting to prove by contradiction it states that if we assume $|x(t)|\nrightarrow \infty $ then $M:=$lim inf $_{t\uparrow b}|x(t)|$

Why can I just not use the fact that $|x(t)|\leq M$ as $t \uparrow b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because a function may fail to converge to $+\infty$ at $b$ AND be unbounded in every neighbourhood of $b$.

For an example, assume that $b=0$ and consider the function defined, for every $t\ne0$, by
$$x(t)=\frac2t\,\sin\left(\frac\pi t\right).$$ Then, for every $n\geqslant0$, 
$$x\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)=0,\qquad x\left(\frac2{4n+1}\right)=4n+1,$$
hence the function $|x|$ neither converges to $+\infty$ at $0$ nor is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: So this function goes to infinity and comes back again?

Comment: In a way, [yes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2sin%28pi%2Ft%29%2Ft).